# Bittorrent protocol TCP communication example

Tags: python, sockets, bittorrent

I'm trying to implement a bittorent client and I got stuck at the part were I succesfully connected to a peer but I don't know how to communicate with the peer.

I managed to decode the torrent metadata file, I succesfully got all the info from there, I connected to a peer with TCP, I send the handshake message, I receive the handshake message back from the peer, but after that I don't receive any message from the peer (I was expecting the have messages). I tried sending an unchoke message to the peer and I started receiving some data but I don't know how to understand that data.

This is what I have until now:

```
s.connect((ip, port))
print "Connected"

message = "%s%s%s%s%s" % (chr(19), "BitTorrent protocol", 8 * chr(0),
                         handshake_params["info_hash"], 
                         handshake_params["peer_id"]

s.send(message)
handshake_data = s.recv(4096)

# unchoke
m = struct.pack(">IB", 1, 1)
s.send(m)
data = s.recv(4096)

print handshake_data
print struct.unpack("B" * len(data), data)
```

And this is the output:

```
BitTorrent protocolp    p�I0a��9"x`��-UT3450-��kP+�BG   ���������
(255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 253, 231, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 127, 255, 251, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 223, 255, 255, 255, 239, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 239, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 191, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 127, 255, 221, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 191, 191, 255, 255, 127, 255, 255, 255, 255, 191, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 191, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 247, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 239, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 191, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 251, 255, 255, 251, 254, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 252, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 4, 191, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 1, 123, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 2, 122, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 2, 126, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 2, 177, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 2, 104, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 1, 37, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 174, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 4, 157, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 3, 172, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 2, 241, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 1, 90, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 3, 251, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 2, 200, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 179, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 180, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 3, 113, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 4, 181, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 1, 16, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 2, 169, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 4, 81, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 2, 57, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 1, 219)
```

The handshake data looks ok. What I can't figure out is why I get so many 255 bytes there. I was trying to decode the message using the length_prefix, message_id, payload format, but since I get so many 255 bytes at the beginning it results in the message having a huge length and I don't have a message that big.

Is there any kind of noise I should try and filter out? If you scroll right a lot you will see that at some point the bytes start being decent but I don't know what to do with the beginning of the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> s.recv(4096)

You're just reading an block of data of some unspecified length, presumably whatever is in the TCP buffer.

Bittorrent is message-based. TCP is a stream of bytes, which means it does not nicely chop the data sent by the remote peer into messages, you will have to do that yourself.

Comment: I know that, but I don't know how to chop the given stream in bittorrent messages. The bittorrent protocol says the message format is a length_prefix (4 bytes big endian) message_id (1 byte) payload (length_prefix - 1 bytes). However the first 4 bytes in the stream are 255 which gives a huge length and I don't even have that many bytes.

Comment: I'm seeing 2 `recv` there. That already tears your stream into two chunks that are not separated at any meaningful boundary. you have to look at the whole stream. Again, doing arbitrary (*up to* 4096 bytes) reads will not give you anything at useful offsets. You're not reasoning about it as continuous stream.

Comment: Yeah and i did check that actually. The first message i receive from recv is the handshake message and I checked that there is nothing left there. All the bits in the first recv message are accounted for and are part of the handshake message. Basically even if I concatenated the two messages and tried to split I would get the same thing because I would succesfully parse the handshake message at the beginning and then I would have 4 255 bytes which should represent the length of the next message but that is invalid because it would be way too big.

Comment: I also just now replaced the second recv with a while in which i keep calling s.recv until I receive a timeout from the socket (to make sure I get everything from the socket buffer) but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Yeah this is embarassing. Apparently I decoded wrongly the handshake message and I thought everything was accounted for, but in fact there were some bytes left at the end which I was missing, and those were exactly the ones I needed which identified the bitfield message. Yeah now I know what I have to do, thanks for everything and sorry. It was a stupid mistake.

Comment: So yeah if everyone is looking at this question looking for answers, the handshake message contains additional bytes from the handshake message. I changed in my code instead of recv(4096) i do a while True: recv(4096) until the socket timeouts (you also need to add a socket.settimeout() otherwise the socket is blocking by default) and the handshake message will contain the bitfield message at the end concatenated.