# peers not sending back unchoke message

Tags: python, networking, struct, p2p, bittorrent

I am creating a bittorrent client and am trying to communicate to peers that I need to be unchoked to eventually receive pieces.

I have been sending unchoke and interested messages to the peers, I expect that they send my an unchoke message back, but have not succeeded in receiving it

I am following this [article](http://markuseliasson.se/article/bittorrent-in-python/) mainly, which states that you must send an interested message after creating a handshake (which I have done successfully)

here is the code I use to create the interested message

```
 12 def generateinterested():
 13   return struct.pack('>iB', 1, 2)
```

as a hexdump this is:

```
00000000: 00 00 00 01 02                                    .....
```

Sending that message gets no reply. A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33461878/bittorrent-protocol-tcp-communication-example) says that you send an unchoke message after the handshake (intstead of interested) which conflicts the original article.

I have attempted this using the following code to create the unchoke message

```
  9 def generateunchoke():
 10   return struct.pack('>iB', 1, 1)
```

as a hexdump this is:

```
00000000: 00 00 00 01 01                                    .....
```

Neither has yielded the result of the peer sending back a unchoke message as I expected. what am I doing wrong here? am I meant to send my interested or unchoke message after handshaking to get receive a unchoke message?

I am getting inconsistent messages. 2% of the time, the peer will send back an unchoke. the other 98% I wait for over a minute and get no reply. Why is this?

in case you are not familiar with bittorrent messages [here](http://jonas.nitro.dk/bittorrent/bittorrent-rfc.html#anchor22) is some aid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending an interested message does not guarantee you get an unchoke message. 
Signalling interest merely means that a peer will consider you as an unchoking candidate. In other words you have to wait. How long depends on the decision-making of the remote peers.

Signalled interest is not a form of request for which there is an expected response. It merely advertises your current state to all peers you are connected to. Some of which may choose to unchoke you at some point in the future, others may not and the unchokes will change over time. They are more likely to unchoke you when you're uploading data to them. See the [bittorrent economics paper](http://bittorrent.org/bittorrentecon.pdf) for a baseline how clients are expected to behave in aggregate.

The [fast extension](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0006.html) provides more prompt behavior during startup. Peers generally follow a common algorithm to calculate a set of pieces which you are allowed to download and then tell you which set they have calculated, you may then request those pieces without being unchoked.

Comment: what is a reasonable amount of time to wait? I wait for up to a thirty second timeout, and still do not get a response.